# sampling NumPy 1d array with controlled randomness

Tags: python, numpy, random, sampling

I have a 1d NumPy array `a` of length `l` and I want to sample `int(np.log(l))` instances from it, but I want the samples to be:

1. quasi-uniformly distributed, and
2. random.

- By `1` I  mean I want to avoid having two samples with distance less than `int(l/int(np.log(l)))`.
- By `2` I mean I don't want to get the same instances as the sample each time.
- I also need to stress that I can't change the randomness seed.

One way is to split the array into `int(np.log(l))` sub-arrays and then randomly sample one from each sub-array, but I am looking for a more efficient implementation since I need to run it several times on a considerable number of data.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([np.random.randint(1000) for _ in range(1000)])
a = np.sort(a)
l = len(a)
random_indices = np.random.randint(0, l, int(np.log(l)))
samples = a[random_indices]
samples = np.sort(samples)
samples
# array([183, 536, 644, 791, 925, 999])
```

I appreciate any comments, suggestions, and helps.

Comment: Did you consider using ```np.random.choice```? if you use it with replace=False and size=int(np.log(l)) I think you will get what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you @Luckk but it is doing what I already did: giving `int(np.log(l))` samples with uniform distribution. I want to make sure I have at least one sample from each chunk.

Comment: The distribution can not be at the same time uniformly distributed and constrained. What you're asking for is mathematically impossible.

Comment: You're right @obchardon I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

For this question, we can use a builtin function in Python: [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.sample)
So the code would be:

```
import numpy as np
import random

a = np.array([i for i in range(1000)])
l = len(a)
random_sample = random.sample(a, int(np.log(l)))
print(random_sample)
```

Would that be acceptable for you?

Comment: Thank you @Nam for your comment. I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: I see. This answer should normally just be a comment, but I don't have the reputation on this site for that. I will find something else.

Answer (score 0):

This comment exhausted the limitations of a comment, hence I post it here.

- Is it important what the values of your NumPy array are? Is it bool? Is it complex?
- You wrote

  > I want to sample `int(np.log(l))` instances

  does it mean that you want to select `int(np.log(l))` indices from the array?
- You wrote

  > avoid having two samples with distance less than `int(l/int(np.log(l)))`

  by sample, do you mean the index or the value? In other words, what is the distance of 2 elements of the array: the difference of the indices or the difference of the values?
- You wrote:

  > don't want to get the same instances as the sample each time

  Do you mean that you don't want to select an index twice or don't want to have two selected indices representing the same value?

If by the distance you meant the difference of index, and you don't want to select and index twice, then I don't understand how your code passes the closeness criterium.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
import math
L=5000
a = np.array([np.random.randint(L) for _ in range(L)])
a = np.sort(a)
random_indices = np.random.randint(0, L, int(np.log(L)))
samples = a[random_indices]
samples = np.sort(samples)
data = pd.DataFrame(data={"index":samples})
data["compared"] = data["index"].shift(-1)
data["dist"] = data["compared"] - data["index"]
print(data)
wrong_indices = data["dist"] < int(L/int(math.log(L)))
print("Indices closer than", int(L/int(math.log(L))), ":")
print(data[wrong_indices][["index","compared"]])
```

The output is:

```
   index  compared    dist
0    255     701.0   446.0
1    701    1537.0   836.0
2   1537    1671.0   134.0
3   1671    2589.0   918.0
4   2589    3393.0   804.0
5   3393    3576.0   183.0
6   3576    4828.0  1252.0
7   4828       NaN     NaN
Indices closer than 625 :
   index  compared
0    255     701.0
2   1537    1671.0
5   3393    3576.0
```

Is it acceptable to have an iterative (aka non-stable) solution? In this case, how about generating `int(np.log(l))` number of points in an efficient way (with NumPy), then throwing out the bad ones, and generating the missing number of points again, and repeating till you get enough good points?